# DBeaver script in linked folder disappears after renaming in Windows

Tags: backup, dbeaver, external-scripts

I changed the location of my Scripts folder from the default C: drive location to a cloud storage location where there is automated backup:

[image]

When I go to open a script in DBeaver, I see these scripts as expected:

[image]

If I edit the name of a script in this **/Scripts_OneDrive** directory, it disappears from DBeaver. For example, I added a suffix to the first script below in the Windows directory:

[image]

Now when I try to open that script in DBeaver, it is nowhere to be found. The original file that I renamed appears empty with messed up meta data showing it was modified in 1969:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this? I can see it being dangerous, where if I accidentally change the name of script it will be gone forever.

At the end of the day, I'm really just trying to have my scripts in a more secure, backed up location versus the C: drive. Any insight would be much appreciated.